# Advanced checking of URL content (characters count, * operator)

Tags: javascript, url, character, detection, ipfs

I'm building FrameworkJS, and one of its usage is to detect its environment.

Recently, I've added these 3 conditions to detect if URL contains the desired text:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("ba"*".ipfs.") > -1) {
       alert("Alert: IPFS!");
}

if(window.location.href.indexOf("/ipfs/Qm") > -1) {
       alert("Alert: IPFS!");
}

if(window.location.href.indexOf("/ipfs/ba") > -1) {
       alert("Alert: IPFS!");
}
```

It displays an alert when the IPFS environment is detected.

Only the last two have worked:

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmc92ioRvt1KB18GanLUq8qMrXoTeaj4m9iXX3NmjaYWTN/

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeignbgeutsyhunhidcki63wmvmjfib7xipmiorwlt3o27aot2ydgwu/#x-ipfs-companion-no-redirect

But the first haven't worked:

https://bafybeignbgeutsyhunhidcki63wmvmjfib7xipmiorwlt3o27aot2ydgwu.ipfs.dweb.link/#x-ipfs-companion-no-redirect

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("ba"*".ipfs.") > -1) {
       alert("Alert: IPFS!");
}
```

How to check if an URL contains "ba" and everything (* operator that works on Shell/Bash) between "ba" and ".ipfs."? What operator and syntax adjustment to use?

Also, an bonus: how to include on this detection, and count/validate how many characters this starting "ba" haves after the protocol (https://) and .ipfs., like here "https://bafybeignbgeutsyhunhidcki63wmvmjfib7xipmiorwlt3o27aot2ydgwu.ipfs." that is "bafybeignbgeutsyhunhidcki63wmvmjfib7xipmiorwlt3o27aot2ydgwu" (should be 59 characters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of regular expressions (regex)?

In your case, you could try matching the URL against `/ba(.*)\.ipfs\./`

So your code would look something like:

```
if(window.location.href.match(/ba(.*)\.ipfs\./)) {
       alert("Alert: IPFS!");
}
```

Feel free to test here: https://regex101.com/

You can learn more about regex in Javascript here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Your answer works like a charm. https://bafybeiagqiib62jmsaephxiiknfu652k3exxgebk6xge3fxxku6eb4entm.ipfs.infura-ipfs.io/#x-ipfs-companion-no-redirect Thanks!

Comment: Also works locally with IPFS Desktop installed: http://bafybeiagqiib62jmsaephxiiknfu652k3exxgebk6xge3fxxku6eb4entm.ipfs.localhost:8080/

Comment: is there a way to get the CI from the url?

Answer (score 1):

Bonus question:

```js
const url = "https://bafybeifoowqb5fhp7vlusauhshfhiygd3g2hgxjkrlnuccw5lx6umrb5oy.ipfs.";

const matches = /ba(.*)\.ipfs\./.exec(url);

console.log(matches[1].length);
```

Comment: when I replace `"https://bafybeiagqiib62jmsaephxiiknfu652k3exxgebk6xge3fxxku6eb4entm.ipfs.infura-ipfs.io/#x-ipfs-companion-no-redirect"` to `window.location.href`, Console says: `Uncaught TypeError: matches is null`

Comment: Here's how I re-implemented it: https://codepen.io/daniellmesquita/pen/YzVojwK?editors=1111

Comment: How to replace the literal text `"https://bafybeiagqiib62jmsaephxiiknfu652k3exxgebk6xge3fxxku6eb4entm.ipfs.infura-ipfs.io/#x-ipfs-companion-no-redirect"` to `window.location.href`?

Answer (score 1):

You should not naively match against `ba` (CIDv1 in base32) and `Qm` (CIDv0 in Base58)   prefix, as CIDv1 could be encoded in different base ([docs](https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/content-addressing/#identifier-formats)).

Use the dedicated library that correctly detects CID in URLs and paths:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-ipfs

Comment: Many thanks! This is the best approach to achieve IPFS environment detection.